# Ajax - success return more than 1 variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Consider the example below:

I do an Ajax call to a php script and get 1 result. PHP echos out the result like below;

```
 echo json_encode($result);
```

Then in Javascript, the following code will retrieve the result.

```
         dataType: "JSON",
         success:function(data){
           var result = data
        }
```

Now I'm trying to see if I can have PHP script echo out 2 result and have Javascript be able to distinguish them with something like the code below;

```
echo json_encode($result);
echo json_encode($result2);


dataType: "JSON",
success:function(data1,data2){
    var result1 = data1
    var result2 = data2
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: what if result 1 and 2 are arrays or array of objects. wouldnt this make it very painful for javascript to loop to seperate them.

Comment: Opps, just realized you're doing AJAX. Your PHP should be on a separate page. See `@d3r1ck`'s answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send an array of values on successful return of AJAX:

```
echo json_encode(array("data1" => $data1, "data2" => $data2));
```

and print like this:

```
success: function(data){
    var res1 = data.data1
    var res2 = data.data2
}
```